# Why does asp .net core not log exceptions in async methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-core

I have an .asp net core project that runs some never ending `async` tasks in Configure method. After noticing that exceptions in these methods were not logged to the console. I just made a little test. Something like this:

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context)

{
        try
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { throw new Exception("My exception"); });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
}
```

Why isn't it logging these exceptions inside `async` methods? If I just throw the exception in Configure it throws without problem and is logged to console.

Comment: All exception thrown in the Task can caught only using AggregateException

Comment: You should replace the return type of your function from "void" to "Task", if you want to be able to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exceptions from async void methods can’t be caught with catch.

These exceptions can be observed using `AppDomain.UnhandledException` or a similar catch-all event for GUI/ASP.NET applications, but using those events for regular exception handling is a recipe for unmaintainability.

More details in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).